# doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents No bundle found

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to generate Getters and Setters for specific document in bundle. It works for entire bundle

```
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle
```

but I can't find out how to specify one document. Entity class is located at

```
src/AppBundle/Document/Settings/Settings.php
```

No one of these worked:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle:Settings
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle:Document:Settings:Settings
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle\Settings
```

**EDIT:**

There is `--document` option that do the trick

```
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle --document Settings
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the odm version, but in the orm ```AppBundle:Settings``` works

Comment: There's [`--filter`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/d728cc1e309475ed52f4cd9aa35208e699941f9e/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Tools/Console/Command/GenerateDocumentsCommand.php#L45-L48) option that could be handy

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for me: `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle --filter Settings` > `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--filter" option does not exist.`